# Speech Recognition through sphinx 4

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4

Hey has anyone used sphinx 4? I want to use it for my project, I installed it and run its HelloWorld demo, the problem is it works fine the first and second times but then when I execute it the third time, it doesnt recognise anything. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your sphinx library , the one that should be imported in your project ? I have implemented it in a project of mine and it works fine. Here is the link from where i learned about it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0f3vvCJWyo. And i also used this one: http://dipayandev.blogspot.ro/2012/03/speech-recognition-by-java-sphinx4.html ( wich explains to you how you can change your grammar file, to recognize whatever you want ).

I know i created a user library in java and then everything went on quite good. Also, try building the program from scratch( meaning you to write the hello world class in java ).

Hope it helps you out. Good luck.

**P.S: Also try adding additional heap memory to your JVM by right clicking on your project: run as-> run configuration-> arguments and type -mx256m.**